# RStudio 0.9x desktop icon won't open in lubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, lxde, lubuntu

I've installed R (3.2.2) in latest lubuntu (`apt-get`) and the RStudio (0.99.489 - Ubuntu 12.04+ 32-bit).  R works from command line, but the IDE fails to launch from the shortcut that installation placed for some reason in the `Graphics` section.  Same with RStudio's shortcut in `Programming`.  When I try and run /usr/share/applications/R.desktop I get:

```
me@system:~$ . /usr/share/applications/R.desktop 
[Desktop: command not found
software: command not found
Science: command not found
Math: command not found
```

And..

```
me@system:~$ . /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop 
[Desktop: command not found
bash: fg: %F: no such job
bash: text/x-r: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-R: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-doc: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-sweave: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-markdown: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-html: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-presentation: No such file or directory
bash: application/x-r-data: No such file or directory
bash: application/x-r-project: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-history: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-r-profile: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-tex: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-markdown: No such file or directory
bash: text/html: No such file or directory
bash: text/css: No such file or directory
bash: text/javascript: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-chdr: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-csrc: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-c++hdr: No such file or directory
bash: text/x-c++src: No such file or directory
```

Grateful for advice how figure out what's going wrong here.

---

Edit: as per request below.

```
me@system:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to *source* a desktop launcher? AFAIK that's not the way to open an application

Comment: Well it wasn't my primary method..

Comment: If it installed correctly, you should be able to launch RStudio from the LXDE desktop's normal application menu - look under 'Programming'

Comment: What do you mean by `the IDE`, in: `but the IDE fails to launch from the shortcut that installation placed for some reason in the Graphics ` what is the name of the program, as it appears in the Graphics menu?

Comment: Also, can you try the command `lsb_release -a` and update the question to include its results? it may lead to additional clues, thanks

Comment: @steeldriver like I said that doesn't work. Nothing happens.

Comment: I've installed the 64-bit deb, and it seems to be possible to start it from the command line simply using `rstudio`; the actual binary executable appears to be `/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio` but it should be symlinked to `/usr/bin/rstudio` - if none of those work, then I suspect something went wrong with the installation.

Comment: Thanks @steeldrive - please see [this log](http://pastebin.com/LCCei4ft)

Comment: How exactly did you install it? Perhaps all the dependencies didn't get resolved?

Comment: I just used the [latest 32 bit ubuntu installer](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/).  Guess I'll try the tarball

Comment: If I were you I'd stick with the .deb file ("installer") at this stage - but I was interested in exactly *how* you installed it once you got it (using the Software Center application? using `dpkg`? using `gdebi`?)

Comment: I vote to close the question because badly formulated question (not RStudio question), unsupported distro, and unsupported IDE version.

Comment: No flies on you!

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight misunderstanding, you seem to be calling it by sourcing, which is usually used for example if you were to source `. ~/.bashrc` to make some setting in effect for your system.

But application shortcut `*.desktop` files are not run this way.  The `.desktop` files contain an `Exec=somecommand` and it is the `somecommand` that is actually run by the system when you double click or run from the menu.

So, if you want to use the terminal to perform exactly the same thing a `*.desktop` does, you need to determine what `Exec=...` command is being run.

You could open any text viewer and figure out what command is run, or just use grep on your command line, for example for my `R.desktop` file I see:

```
$ grep '^Exec' /usr/share/applications/R.desktop
Exec=R
```

This tells me that all my `R.desktop` is doing is running the command `R`

Thus, to do the equivalent of this `R.desktop` shortcut, all I have to do is type `R` on command prompt, so I do that and I get R to start

```
$ R
```

So just check in your `R.desktop` file, see what command comes after `Exec=` , and run that.

Comment: Thanks. `Exec=R`.  But as I said I know that runs in terminal.  It also has its own IDE, which I cannot run.  More importantly I [can't run RStudio...](http://pastebin.com/giWvXe3u)

Comment: Thanks, your rstudio.desktop looks identical to mine, so the only thing I can think of now are system differences. For system info could you run `lsb_release -a` and include the results in the original question? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, `lsb_release...` info helps eliminate any doubts about wrong version installed, as you have the latest 15.10 and rstudio 0.99 ... is for Ubuntu 12.04+, so you should be fine in terms of version issues. Now, programs often give away helpful error info when run from command prompt. When I run rstudio's command, on my command prompt: `/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio`, I don't get errors and rstudio starts after a moment. What text or errors, if any, show up for you when you run that command? And as usual, update the question to include this, thanks

Comment: That's the same error as when I just run `rstudio` - `error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.  I've tried [installing libgstreamer with apt-get](http://pastebin.com/LCCei4ft).

Comment: I see. That error info gives another lead to chase down, so to figure this out, could you run two commands, and include the results in the original question: `uname -a`, and `dpkg --get-selections | grep '^r-'` , thanks

Comment: [Here you go.](http://pastebin.com/d05wWQpd)  Appreciate your help dude.

Comment: No problem, I plan to use R, Linux for a long time so whatever solutions we develop will probably help me in the future. So your uname and dpkg looks good so far. Now I know when installing other software in the past, if I didn't `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to ensure I have the latest updates, some software failed to install properly. Even if you already did this, could you try these commands, and then re-try installing rstudio, and then run `rstudio` from command prompt, letting us know if it is the same error or different error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try reinstall using terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio_file_name.deb
```

there might be an warning about missing libgstreamer0.10 package.
Start Sinaptic Package Manager and try to find "libgstreamer" there.
In my case there was no such version, so i goolge it:

[debian.org says](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgstreamer0.10-0) its part of **jessie main** 
so you need add

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

to your repositories (Sinaptic Package Manager>Settigs>Repositories, Software & Updates->Other Software)
and later fix "NO_PUBKEY" issue via http://ccm.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error

And now try to install rstudio again

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio_file_name.deb
```